# On android, how can I unzip more than one zip files at once?

Tags: applications, apk, zip

In PC you can choose more than one separate zip files and extract to "zipname" folder all by selecting at once, how can I do the same in Android.
I've tried ES file explorer, Z Archiver etc but they all seem to work only for multipart zip files and not for multiple separate zips.

Comment: Either you install some advanced File explorers like `ES File explorer`/`File commander`, Or You could install Applications like 'RAR'.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so just tried another app [RAR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarlab.rar) by Rarsoft and it did the job perfectly, though extracted all the zips to same folder....enough for me.

Comment: @beeshyams Oh actually, I thought it'll make the question look a spam one cause I myself answering just after minutes of asking it. Now added.

Comment: 1. If you are the developer , you can mention in answer, that's fine 2. Even if you are not, self answering the question is encouraged here, and linking the app helps people easily locate on play store. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solid Explorer works like a charm. You can try it out, but it's a paid app.
You select all the files, like on a desktop and choose the extract option. The contents of the zip file are extracted to the respective folders.